# textbox text remove last character

Tags: c#, .net

If the string is > 8, I need to remove the last character

How is this possible?

```
private void textBoxNewPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBoxNewPassword.TextLength == 9)
        textBoxNewPassword.Text = textBoxNewPassword.Text.Remove((textBoxNewPassword.Text.Length - 1), 1);
}
```

The code appears to do nothing.

Comment: Could you just take advantage of setting the `MaxLength` property on the textbox and setting it to 8? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx

Comment: Can't you make it so the length max is  8 in the textBox properties?  Is this a windows component?

Comment: I made the Max length 8 but some people keep typing and don't realize that the textbox is not accepting more text. I need to inform them that they typed more than 8 and show them what will be considered as a password if they simply proceed.

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't work? It worked for me...

Comment: @CocoaDev How does that not have the same effect as setting the textbox text to the same length string, I do not understand the issue, if you only allow 8 then it only shows 8, the system generally offers a sound to notify the user that no more input is accepted.

Comment: This code appears very sound.  It worked when I tested it in a sandbox, and everything looks kosher when I checked it in Reflector.  `Substring` would work fine but I think the larger question being begged here is why this code appears to do nothing.

Comment: @YYY - that is a good question. I assumed it was bad code or I used it improperly. Substring does work better. I didnt think of it (thanks for everyone else who did)

Comment: Ack, I see the problem.  `Remove`'s first argument is zero-based, which makes sense since you might have to get the first character now that I think of it.  `Length` returns a one-based length.  So `12345689` will return `length 9`, but attempting to punch `8` into it will return `9`, since as far as `Remove` is concerned, `1` is at space `0`!  I will put this into an answer to clarify this for anyone else who reads this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx), where the first parameter is the starting index and 2nd parameter is the number of characters. Also if you need to check if the length is greater than 8 the do:

```
if (textBoxNewPassword.Text.Length > 8)
    textBoxNewPassword.Text = textBoxNewPassword.Text.SubString(0,8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take an 8-character substring:

```
textBoxNewPassword.Text = textBoxNewPassword.Text.Substring(0, 8);
```

Better yet, set the `MaxLength` property on your `TextBox` to 8.

Answer (score 2):

The spirit of your usage of `Remove()` is not improper, but you are forgetting that the first argument of `Remove(int, int)` is [zero-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx).  Therefore, when you establish that in your `if` statement that the length is 9 (`TextBoxBase.TextLength` simply overlays `TextBoxBase.String.Length` in most - but not all - cases), you are addressing the last character in your string when you `Remove` at position 8.  Your code would have worked if you used instead:

```
textBoxNewPassword.Text = textBoxNewPassword.Text.Remove((textBoxNewPassword.Text.Length - 2), 1);
```

But I think everyone can agree that the `Substring` solution is cleaner and less brittle.  I only mention this so we can understand why it was apparently doing nothing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly as your question asks

```
    private void textBoxNewPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxNewPassword.Text.Length > 8)
        {
            textBoxNewPassword.Text = textBoxNewPassword.Text.Substring(0, textBoxNewPassword.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

You said you only wanted to remove the last character if it's over a 8 characters long.

Comment: Although you are doing the literal definition of what he asked, I think what he was going for was a maximum of 8 chars.  Although you are right, by what he said if you copy/paste 10 chars you should 9 chars, but I think he was *trying* to say he would want only 8.

Comment: That's why I made sure I explicitly stated, I was giving an answer to exactly what he asked for. I agree with setting the max value for the text box, but, I had to go by what his question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible generic solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "The max length is seven".RemoveChars(7);

    }

    public static string RemoveChars(this string text, int length)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Length > length)
            text = text.Remove(length, text.Length - length);
        return text;
    }
```

Hope this help.